# Return all joined rows in SQL

Tags: mysql, wordpress, join

So I am messing around with wordpress and trying to get all the rows a row joins to. For now, I can only seem to get one row it joins to. I know there has to be some element of GROUP BY, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

```
SELECT posts.*, meta.meta_value
                FROM wp_g6exrf_posts as posts
                LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_g6exrf_postmeta as meta
                ON meta.post_id = posts.ID
                WHERE ! ( posts.post_status = 'auto-draft' ) 
                GROUP BY meta.post_id
```

So I am joining to the meta table and expecting more than one column to meet the join condition.

Sincere thanks for any help. It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Impossible to diagnose without seeing the data in the tables.  Why do you have an exclamation point after "WHERE"?   That's not valid Sql Server syntax.

Comment: I removed the sql server tag; WordPress is a MySQL client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`postmeta` makes very little sense without seeing `meta_key`.

GROUP BY doesn't make sense unless you're doing some kind of aggregate. It's crushing your multiple rows for each post into one, and returning just one of your meta_value items, a randomly chosen one.

Try this:

```
SELECT posts.*, 
       meta.meta_key, meta.meta_value
  FROM wp_g6exrf_posts as posts
  LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_g6exrf_postmeta as meta ON meta.post_id = posts.ID
 WHERE ! ( posts.post_status = 'auto-draft' ) 
 ORDER BY posts.id, meta.meta_key, meta.meta_value
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Works great... For future reference, is there any way in SQL to create a array of joined values instead of creating a separate for for each join? I realize you could split it in to two queries to achieve this, but would be nice to be able to do it in one. Regardless, thanks again.